# SharePoint 2013 Bing Maps with GeoLocation Column

Tags: internet-explorer, maps, sharepoint-2013, bing-maps

List with GeoLocation column in SharePoint 2013, displaying the below message on IE (10). Where its working fine on Google Chrome and Mozila FireFox.

**

> Sorry, Bing Maps isn't available in your region. Please contact your
>   administrator.

**

Tried the following
1) compatibility view, not working
2) InPrivate window - not working

Don't know why its happening!!!

Comment: What are your Language and Region settings? It might cause a problem with a specific culture that you don't have on FF and Chrome since they have their own settings (page preferences...)

Comment: On my environment, installed English and Arabic language packs, but right now working with only English (en-us) publishing site.

Comment: It might be related to your desktop environment, arabic language could be the reason you cannot get certain features. Try to change your language preferences in your browser or/and in your system.

Comment: In control panel, also try going to Region -> Location and setting the value to United States.

Comment: can you show your settings here?

Answer (score 0):

Apply en-US language setting to your IE browser.